# How to have a cache when there is no connection in my app?

Tags: android, database, caching

I created a simple social app ,i'm using a Mysql database ,what i'm looking for is how to make the app work even without any connection , what i mean is how to have a cache of the data to get the the last update when the connection was here .
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a local database. SQLite is probably your best option. It will have to mirror your main database and then allow synch operations when connections are available.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how to mirror my main database?

Comment: You build all the same tables in both databases. You should probably do all operations on the local database and then have synch operation which runs whenever the connection is available.

Comment: So i need to double all my queries that i used for the mysql ?

Comment: No, but you have to work out a system for synchronizing the two versions of your database. You could have a flag field in your local database, for example, to indicate that the record has been moved to the master. Then when you do a sync, you look for all records without the flag and then copy them up.